# How are the entries of a random effect matrix (Z) in a linear mixed model determined?

Tags: mixed-model

I am working with linear mixed effect models in `lme4` and I struggle to understand how the random effect model matrix (Z) works in this context.

Suppose I have a linear mixed model with n observations and a single random factor with q clusters, and I decide to only include a random intercept, so the size of the random effect model matrix Z is nxq. 
Suppose our observations are students' grades and we cluster the data by teacher. Then the rows of Z correspond to students and columns to teachers. If the i-th student is in the j-th teacher's class the i,j-entry of matrix Z is 1 and all other entries in i-th row are 0.

Is this how matrix Z works in general, i.e. as a sort of "indicator" of which cluster is relevant for each observation? Or can the entries of matrix Z be other than 0 and 1 and if so, when would that be the case?

Also, if I decide to add more random effects, say one with q' clusters, for matrix Z it only means I add q' (or 2q' for intercept&slope) columns to it, leave the rows as they are and again indicate the relevant cluster as described above?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so it will be 0/1 for intercepts and the value of the input for the corresponding slope.  if it helps just think of the random effects as interactions: interaction indicator with intercept is 0/1, with real value is real value...